# Cannot find Kotlin classes when compiling IntelliJBehave

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I am trying to compile IntelliJBehave to add support for scala.  When I compile, I get the following errors:

```
/home/hobbitProg/devWorkspace/IntelliJBehave/src/com/github/kumaraman21/intellijbehave/kotlin/psi/NavigableKotlinPsiAnnotation.kt
Error:(5, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(12, 21) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetElement
/home/hobbitProg/devWorkspace/IntelliJBehave/src/com/github/kumaraman21/intellijbehave/kotlin/psi/NavigableKotlinPsiElement.kt
Error:(6, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(13, 33) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetElement
Error:(22, 34) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetElement
/home/hobbitProg/devWorkspace/IntelliJBehave/src/com/github/kumaraman21/intellijbehave/kotlin/psi/NavigableKotlinPsiMethod.kt
Error:(5, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(12, 21) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetElement
/home/hobbitProg/devWorkspace/IntelliJBehave/src/com/github/kumaraman21/intellijbehave/kotlin/support/services/KotlinAnnotationsLoader.kt
Error:(8, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(9, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(10, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(29, 13) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetAnnotationsIndex
Error:(30, 35) Kotlin: Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
Error:(32, 73) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetFunction
Error:(34, 49) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: LightClassUtil
/home/hobbitProg/devWorkspace/IntelliJBehave/src/com/github/kumaraman21/intellijbehave/kotlin/support/services/KotlinPsiClassesLoader.kt
Error:(4, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(5, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(6, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: kotlin
Error:(21, 58) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetFile
Error:(22, 17) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: declarations
Error:(23, 24) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: LightClassUtil
Error:(23, 51) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: it
Error:(23, 58) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: JetClass
```

I realize that the JetElement, JetAnnotationsIndex, LightClassUtil, and JetClass classes are not being found by the Kotlin compiler.  Could someone please let me know where I can find the library that defines these classes?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin was compiled against an old version of the Kotlin plugin. To compile the plugin, you need to add the Kotlin plugin to the classpath of your IntelliJ IDEA SDK and to update the code of IntelliJBehave so that it references Kotlin classes according to their current names (KtElement, KtAnnotationsIndex etc).